How to use grep string that has double quotes in it
So I'm running a simple alias called vpn which runs a command and has an output, which I put into a .txt file.
If interested to what exactly then here is the alias
alias vpn="docker exec -it qbittorrent curl -sS https://ipinfo.io/json > $HOME/vpnstatus.txt" and the output when I use cat vpnstatus.txt;
{
  "ip": "123.123.123.123",
  "city": "Star_City",
  "region": "On_the_moon",
  "country": "far_far_away",
  "loc": "some_random_numbers",
  "org": "some_random_ips_info",
  "postal": "who_knows",
  "timezone": "Darkside/Moon",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}

So I thought, well I use grep and get what I want (grep is basically one of the few commands I have ran into and thought I had a clue how to use) but since the output has the same phrase "ip" recurring I get two lines. grep "ip" vpnstatus.txt;
"ip": "123.123.123.123",
"readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"

Have tried altarring the command eg grep "ip: " vpnstatus.txt but then there is no return value..
My question is how to use grep and obtain the info I'm interested in, which is the first line of the output. I plan to write another alias for the 'grep' part of this and combine the two aliases && and embedded them into my .basharc for easy and visual confirmation upon each login.

The string you want to grep for is "ip": , but the string you are using is ip: .  The double quotes are processed by the shell.  To include the literal double quotes in the pattern, you need to quote them as '"ip": '.
However, the correct (as in "robust") way to parse a JSON document is with a JSON parser, such as jq:
$ curl -sS https://ipinfo.io/json | jq -r '.ip'
xxx.yyy.zzz.70

This returns the decoded ("raw", -r) string value of the top-level key ip from the document returned from curl.
Or, using Miller (mlr):
$ curl -sS https://ipinfo.io/json | mlr --j2c --headerless-csv-output cut -f ip
xxx.yyy.zzz.70

This also parses the JSON from the curl command, extracts (with the cut sub-command) the value of the ip key and outputs a header-less CSV document with the value.

I really don't know how to execute these steps that are required to archive what you are suggesting. If I would have to guess then I think you are saying that I should start with making a .json file?

@Arelius You already have a JSON file. You call it $HOME/vpnstatus.txt.  It's only necessary to store it if you need the other information in the file for something. For the sake of this answer, I did not care for the file and instead used the output of curl directly.

Yes and that is fine, I don't care for the file either and I'm sorry I'm not experienced at all in Linux terminology and commands! jg dose not seem to be installed whereis jg outputs: jg:

@Arelius The command is jq, not jg. If it is not installed, you should be able to install it using your ordinary package manager.

yes sorry, that was a typo but yeah its not installed and yes its possible to install, sudo apt install --dry-run jq (I just wanted to check if it was available, so I did --dry-run). For now I made a executable .sh file nano $HOME/vpnip.sh -> added these 3 lines: docker exec -it qbittorrent curl -sS https://ipinfo.io/json > $HOME/vpnstatus.txt grep '"ip":' vpnstatus.txt rm $HOME/vpnstatus.txt -> made it executable using chmod +x vpnip.sh -> ran $HOME/vpnip.sh and got the output. However, I'll give the suggestion a try when I'm home and accept the answer ofc, thank you!
